# How to make size filter like ecommerce app have

Tags: ios, swift, filter, size, e-commerce

i am trying to make an app in which there is a size filter button which upon click opens up a size filter. Don't know how to start as i am new to designing. please help me. And also want that by default one value selected from like shown in the image with the tick mark image like its selected

[screenshot 1 filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyglA.png)

[screenshot 2 filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBIkz.png)

[screenshot 3 filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP3Pl.png)

Comment: please help me as i am new to ios programming

Answer (score 0):

Use two UITableViews for the simplest. One for the left half, other for the right half. Each of entry will be the row.

You start learning UITableViews first. Basic iOS development can be achieved with the help of UITableViews only.

**Edit -**
You can download sample code from - 
https://github.com/nikusingla/Ecommerce-Filter

Comment: basic tableview i know but if you can give one code example then it would be easy

Comment: Hello niku, thanks for the effort u took on creating the demo for me. But can you make one complete demo for one filter lets say for price and beside it shows price list with any price as by default selected with tickmark. It would be helpful and be more clear to me if you are free then only

Comment: hey niku, i have done mostly from the sample code u gave, now there are some issues, can u guide me?. Please give me your mail id so that i can share my code with you

Comment: sure ping me at neeraj.singla@hotmail.com at skype only.

Comment: we can do skype if its ok with you niku